# WinForms how to call a Double-Click Event on a Button?

Tags: winforms, events, button, double-click

Rather than making an event occur when a button is clicked once, I would like the event to occur only when the button is double-clicked. Sadly the double-click event doesn't appear in the list of Events in the IDE.

Anyone know a good solution to this problem? Thank you!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.button.doubleclick(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No the standard button does not react to double clicks.   See the documentation for the [Button.DoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.doubleclick.aspx) event.   It doesn't react to double clicks because in Windows buttons always react to clicks and never to double clicks.

Do you hate your users?  Because you'll be creating a button that acts differently than any other button in the system and some users will never figure that out.

That said you have to create a separate control derived from `Button` to event to this (because [SetStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle.aspx) is a protected method)

```
public class DoubleClickButton : Button
{
    public DoubleClickButton()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardClick | ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, true);
    }
}
```

Then you'll have to add the `DoubleClick` event hanlder manually in your code since it still won't show up in the IDE:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1()  {
        InitializeComponent();
        doubleClickButton1.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(doubleClickButton1_DoubleClick);
    }

    void doubleClickButton1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)  {
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to link these two classes DoubleClickButton and Form1, i mean how we set the ControlStyles of a button on Form1 from a different class ?

Comment: i'm no expert but setstyle can also be used without inheritance  see answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36771882/how-can-i-make-a-button-that-can-sendkeys-into-a-datagridview-so-i-need-to-some

Comment: Assuming I have a group of buttons that will require doubleClick event.
Do I have to add them one by one? Or there's a way to get all the group buttons and assign them into that method?
I was trying to to this but I'm unable to set the event to the group buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. Code works.

```
public class DoubleClickButton : Button
            {
                public DoubleClickButton()
                {
                    SetStyle(ControlStyles.StandardClick | 
ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick, true);
                }
            }

 DoubleClickButton button = new DoubleClickButton();
 button.DoubleClick += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //codes
        };
```

Answer (score -1):

i used to add MouseDoubleClick event on my object like:

`this.pictureBox.MouseDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox_MouseDoubleClick);`

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.

Answer (score -2):

A double click is simply two regular click events within a time t of each other.

Here is some pseudo code for that assuming t = 0.5 seconds

```
button.on('click' , function(event) {
    if (timer is off or more than 0.5 milliseconds)
        restart timer
    if (timer is between 0 and 0.5 milliseconds)
        execute double click handler
})
```

Comment: Do not do this! You'll be ignoring the user's double-click speed setting. Windows will tell you if it was a double-click if you follow the other answer to derive from Button and create a double-clickable button.

Comment: It has nothing to do with doublé click