# Button double click event

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to add a double click event to a button in winforms but it never executes in run-time. My buttons are created dynamically at run-time

This is what I am trying at the moment:

```
buttons[r][c].MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(mouseDBL_Click); 

private void mouseDBL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

I also tried:

```
buttons[r][c].DoubleClick += new EventHandler(gridDBL_Click);

private void gridDBL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

I really don't understand why this does not work.

Comment: Have you tried the .Click event?

Comment: I want a Click and a double click event is that posible

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MouseClick` event and check the `Clicks` property

```
private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Clicks >= 2)
    {
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Apologies, I just tried it and it seems to not work. I looked up more about why this is. You can find the answer here:

[WinForms how to call a Double-Click Event on a Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486245/winforms-how-to-call-a-double-click-event-on-a-button)

Very odd that it is included if it does not work. In fact, that event doesn't even seem to fire.

Comment: I didn't even know that property was there! Awesome!

Comment: yes it works, thank you very much. My code is like:
(Use the link above)
DoubleClickButton button = new DoubleClickButton();
 button.DoubleClick += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//codes
};