# Dynamically create buttons and add events to it

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I need to dynamically create buttons (one for loop) and add "onClick" and "doubuleClick" events on it.

I did it like this:

```
  Button bt = new Button();

  bt.Click += bt_Click;         
  bt.DoubleClick += bt_DoubleClick;

  private void bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        label1.Text = this.Text;
  }

  private void bt_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        //some code
  }
```

First: My "bt_Click" method gets "main form" text in "label1". In debugger I see that sender is a button. What is wrong with it?

Second: My "bt_DoubleClick" event do not react at all, am I doing something wrong here?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this it is to use "datagrid".
Datagread has the great support for all events and for organization of items (image, text and so on).
I have made "save" or "open" dialog form to browse content from remote SFTP server, very easy with datagrad, but I had a problem to do it with buttons or labels.

Answer (score 3):

You should cast **sender** to **Button** to get the bt.Text:

```
Button bt = new Button();
bt.Click += bt_Click;
bt.Text = "click me";
bt.Location = new Point(100,100);
this.Controls.Add(bt);

private void bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = (sender as Button).Text;
}
```

Buttons doesn't react to double click event. You can read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486245/winforms-how-to-call-a-double-click-event-on-a-button) in detail.

Comment: Thank you ! First problem has been solved by the cast sender to Button. Can I do anything to improvise "doubleClick", I need It to make form which will open folders content on double click (like in windows)

Comment: You could use a Label or an Image for the doubleclick, you just can't use a button i'm afraid.

Comment: It works with label. The little problem with label is harder to stylize label (image beside the text, like folders in window). Label do not have method "TextImageRelation".

Answer (score 1):

In response to the first question, if I understand you correctly, in `this.Text`, `this` refers to the form because the method `bt_Click` is a member of the Main Form class.  I think you might have meant to do:

```
private void bt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        label1.Text = (Button)sender.Text;
  }
```

Second: Is this just a case of the bt_Click handler firing twice?