# How to prevent a textbox inside Webbrowser control from losing focus when user clicks outside webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, web-controls, inputsimulator

I have a winform application in which I have a [Virtual Keypad](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/). The following code (with `textBox1` as winform textbox works fine:

```
 protected void touchScreen1_OnUserControlButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Focus();
          InputSimulator inputSimulator = new InputSimulator();
          inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyDown(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.NUMPAD1); 
        }
```

But problem is that I am going to be typing inside a textbox which is not a windows forms control. I will be typing in a textbox which is a part of webpage loaded in webbrowser. Therefore I have no context. I can not explicit shift the focus to it. What do I do? Everytime I click the virtual key I have designed, it takes the focus out of the textbox in webcontrol and therefore does not type.

Comment: [How to create a Button that can send keys to a conrol without losing focus - Virtual Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36771882/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei How do you guys know all this stuff? Anyways, post it as an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Try the solution and let me know if it solves your problem, then let me know to mark it as an exact duplicate.

Comment: @RezaAghaei do duplicate marks have any bad effect on user account? If yes, your solution did not work. If no, your solution worked flawlessly :P

Comment: @RezaAghaei I tried your solution and it seems that it works well for buttons but it does not work for forms. I mean if by accident, I click anywhere on the vacant space  between buttons , webbrowser loses focus. Even though I added     `CommonFunctions.SetStyle(this., ControlStyles.Selectable, false);`

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out the solution to that on my own. (placed everything inside a panel)

Comment: No the duplicate doesn't have any bad impact. It just lets the other users know the question has been answered in another linked question. That's Why I voted up your question, because in future someone else also can have the same question.

Comment: Well in that case your answer worked perfectly ! Thank you.