# Capture all Keyboard input, regardless of what control has focus in Windows Form applicaion

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, devexpress

We are using the windows form application on a tough pad (touchscreen device).

want to show the on screen key board when user click the text box or any input control , rather then handling this event is there any way to handle this on the application level to show and hide the windows on screen keyboard

Comment: Do you use Devexpress controls?

Comment: Yes using devexpress v 19.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36773585/3110834

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress editors, as well as regular .NET editors, do not affect OnScreenKeyboard's behavior. I suggest that you use one of the approaches described here to display it - [Automatically pop up tablet touch keyboard on WinForms input focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36179917/automatically-pop-up-tablet-touch-keyboard-on-winforms-input-focus).